# after closing the Alert Window, the submit button is not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click, save

Im stucked in this problem where when i detect identical Value, when it is on submit and the Error is triggered , the button is unclickable like its stuck on saving. Can someone help me with this situation?

Heres my Jquery

```
  $("#btnSaveShift").on('click', function (e) {

        var gvDetDDLs = $('#positionShiftGrid').find("input[name=shiftDay]");
        $.each(gvDetDDLs, function () {
            var duplicateExists = false;
            var ddlShift = $("#ddlShiftDay option:selected").text();
            var currVal = $(this).val();
            gvDetDDLs.not(this).each(function () {
                if (ddlShift == currVal) {
                    duplicateExists = true;
                }
            });
            if (duplicateExists) {
                alert("Duplicate entry is not allowed");
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }

        });
        return true;

    });
```

Comment: and what does your html look like?

Comment: you can use onsubmit event handler, so you wont need to call preventdefault(), just return true or false

Comment: you aren't comparing anything that is found in `gvDetDDLs.not(this)` instead you are just comparing `ddlShift == currVal` which is from outside the loop!! why you need that loop then?

Comment: @rps the loop is to check the grid value and check if the value on the dropdown is identical to the grid value

Answer (score 1):

In first, you should check this on form submit rather than click on button.

In this case, the e.preventDefault murder the button behavior.

Comment: hmm . . done checking on form submit.on form submit, same happens. after the alert message show. . the submit button is not functioning / not clickable .

Comment: Can you feed us with hosted code on http://jsfiddle.net/, it will be easly to test your source

Answer (score 0):

if you want your button to work even after error remove prevent default and return false in your code

Comment: after removing returns , the loop is not stopped when the condition is true

Comment: can you put it on jsfiddle?